# urlib error: "urllib.error.URLError: <urlopen error no host given>"

Tags: python, url

I've gotten this error copying a tutorial line by line. Here it is:

```
endpoint = 'https:///maps.googleapi.com/maps/api/directions/json?'
origin = ('London').replace(' ', '+')
destination = ('Heathrow').replace(' ', '+')
nav_request = 'origin={} &destination={} &key={}' .format(origin,destination,googleDir_key)
request = endpoint + nav_request
response = urllib.request.urlopen(request).read()
directions = json.loads(response)
print(directions)
```

Comment: Unless you really need to get technical, I don't think anyone uses `urllib`; most use [`requests`](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/).

Comment: `.replace(' ', '+')` doesn't make sense either for strings without whitespace then to do `nav_request = 'origin={} &destination={} &key={}' .format(origin,destination,googleDir_key)` with whitespace in the strings themselves. In other words, you seem to be introducing whitespace _after_ you tried to replace it.

Answer (score 0):

Your URL has no hostname. Scheme, colon, two slashes, hostname, slash, path, optional question mark and query string, optional hash and fragment. You have three consecutive slashes.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should probably be using the [`requests`](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/) library, but your issue seems to lie in string formatting. For example:

```
origin = ('London').replace(' ', '+')
```

There is no whitespace to be replaced by `+` in `'London'`. The same for `'('Heathrow').replace(' ', '+')'`. Then you introduce the whitespace in `nav_request = 'origin={} &destination={} &key={}'` but it's too late. `London'.replace(' ', '+')` will still be `'origin=London '`.

Maybe the following:

```
nav_request = 'origin={}+&destination={}+&key={}'.format(origin,destination,googleDir_key)
```

Comment: Or better yet, use `urllib.parse.urlencode()` like the tutorial *should* have shown.

Answer (score 0):

A couple of things:

1- You have three slashes after 'https:'. This is how you access a file (i.e. file:///blah.txt), however it's not valid for HTTP.  While a browser will correct this, it won't work with urllib or requests.

2- You have unescaped spaces the way you defined your navrequest. I'd suggest you do your replace on the built navrequest instead of each component so it's only done once (easier to read as well).

PS - As others have stated, I would suggest using the requests module (or grequests if you want to operate asynchronously).

Answer (score 0):

It because of you put an extra / after https, so urllib can not detect host name.
In your case consider following code example :

```
from urllib.parse import urlparse
endpoint = 'https:///maps.googleapi.com/maps/api/directions/json'
endpoint = urlparse(endpoint)
print(endpoint.netloc)
print(endpoint)
```

Output will be :

```
''
ParseResult(scheme='https', netloc='', path='/maps.googleapi.com/maps/api/directions/json', params='', query='', fragment='')
```

Now remove **Extra / after https:** your endpoint variable will be modified. now run the previous code again:

```
from urllib.parse import urlparse
endpoint = 'https://maps.googleapi.com/maps/api/directions/json'
endpoint = urlparse(endpoint)
print(endpoint.netloc)
print(endpoint)
```

Output will be:

```
maps.googleapi.com
ParseResult(scheme='https', netloc='maps.googleapi.com', path='/maps/api/directions/json', params='', query='', fragment='')
```

**Now you see the difference**